# How to assign random priorities to multiple instances of c++ class?

Tags: c++, class, multiple-instances

I am writing a network program in c++.  I have to assign priority for more than 2 instances of sender class. But I am unable to create the logic of this problem. One of the instance of class should be selected randomly. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

Would something along these lines work?

```
class Sender {
public:
    Sender() : _prio(getRandomNumber()) {}
};
```